# All Orchard module projects have broken references

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

Installed Orchard CMS using Web Platform Installer and Web Matrix. The Orchard site loads fine but when trying to open any of the module projects, they won't compile. For example when I open `Orchard.Blogs.csproj` all the references that start with Orchard.* are broken. I tried adding all module projects to a Visual Studio solution and still couldn't compile due to missing references. Next, I tried copying all DLLs from `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\My Web Sites\Orchard\App_Data\Dependencies` to `%ProgramFiles%\Reference Assemblies` to no avail.

Isn't there any way I can compile Orchard Modules in Visual Studio with a Web PI installation?

**Update:** Orchard.Web does not compile even when opening solution by clicking the Visual Studio button in WebMatrix. I wonder how this is supposed to work!

Comment: Please read the release notes: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Orchard-1-8-1.Release-Notes#Whatfiletodownload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Project compiled after I cloned the Orchard git repository and built it in Visual Studio. So my conclusion is that you cannot debug Orchard with a WebPI installation.